Foriegn key Fields isn't translated in django admin page with django-parler
I am using django-parler to translate models. In django admin page, When I change the language, the foriegn key isn't changing to current language, always displaying default language. enter image description here
class Country(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields( 
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True),
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    )
    def __str__(self):
        # return self.name
        return self.safe_translation_getter('name', any_language=True)

class Tour(TranslatableModel): 
    translations = TranslatedFields( 
        title=models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True), 
    ) 
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

I tried customizing admin form.
class Tour(TranslatableModel): 
    translations = TranslatedFields( 
        title=models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True), 
    ) 
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

class TourAdminForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    self.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.language('es') #for debug spanish lang
    print(self.fields['country'].queryset) # prints the translation, but doesn't display in admin page

